# Create UITableView Section for unique dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdate

I'm looking to create a section in a `UITableView` for each unique date.

My data is formatted as an array of objects, each containing an `NSDate` inside.

Originally, I had converted each date to a string using dateFormatter @"yyyy-MM-dd" and compared date strings accordingly. But this is slow and seems like the wrong way.

I also tried removing the time from the `NSDate` by using:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: trip.startTime];
[components setHour: 0];
[components setMinute: 0];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
```

But when using the array function:

```
[allDays indexOfObject:newDate]
```

I never got a match on duplicate dates.  Does anyone have an idea on how to do this cleanly?

Comment: If you can encapsulte the dates, and you require order, override `compare:` and use an NSSet for quick uniquing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, actually what I ended up doing was creating a Dictionary of Arrays to store my Objects.
Each key in the dictionary was a day, and the object was an array of my objects (trips)

```
for(Trip *trip in allTrips)
{

    NSString *dateString = [self dayString:trip.startTime];
    NSMutableArray *dayArray = [dict objectForKey:dateString];

    //is the day in the dictionary?
    if (dayArray == nil)
    {
        //This day is not in the dictionary

        //create an empty array
        dayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //add the array to the dictionary
        [dict setObject:dayArray forKey:dateString];

    }

    //add the trip to the array
    [dayArray addObject:trip];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOfObject:` uses the `isEqual:` method to compare the objects. So you might override it in a custom subclass:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object
{
    NSDateComponents* c1= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: self ];
    NSDateComponents* c2= [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]  components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: object ];
    return [c1 isEqual: c2];
}
```